# Evaluate double integral (Need help picking $u$ and $v$)

Tags: calculus

Evaluate
$$
\iint_R 8(x^2+y^2)(x^2-y^2)dA
$$
where $R$ is a region in the first quadrant of $xy$-plane bounded by the circles $x^2+y^2=1,\ x^2+y^2=4$, and the line $y=x+1,\ y=x-1$.

Ok I need help picking $u$ and $v$. I have tried $u^2=x^2+y^2$, and $v^2=x^2-y^2$ but I'm having a hard time simplifying the Jacobian and the integral.

Comment: Any chance your first equation should be $x^2+y^2=1$?

Comment: Yes, sorry it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your region looks like so:

[image]

The inner and outer circles can be written as 
$$g(x,y)=1 \mbox{ or } g(x,y)=4,$$ 
where $g(x,y)=x^2+y^2$.  The lines can be written as 
$$f(x,y)=-1 \mbox{ or } f(x,y)=1,$$ 
where $f(x,y)=x-y$.

So, set $u=x^2+y^2$ and $v=x-y$, because these expressions are constant on the boundary of the region.  The bounds for $u$ will be 1 and 4 and the bounds for $v$ will be -1 and 1.  You can then solve that system for $x$ and $y$.  The determinant of your Jacobian matrix should look something like

$$\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2 u-v^2}}.$$

**A little more detail**

If you set $u=x^2+y^2$ and $v=x-y$ and solve for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $u$ and $v$, one solution should be

$$x=\frac{1}{2} \left(v+\sqrt{2 u-v^2}\right)$$

and

$$y=\frac{1}{2} \left(v+\sqrt{2 u-v^2}\right).$$

I solved these equations with Mathematica.  One way to do it by hand would be to write $y=x-v$, plug that into the $u$ equation to get $u=x^2+(x-v)^2$ and solve that quadratic for $x$.  You can then get $y$.  However you do it, plugging these into your integrand and simplifying, you get

$$8\left(x^2+y^2\right)\left(x^2-y^2\right) =8 u v \sqrt{2 u-v^2}.$$

The $\sqrt{2u-v^2}$ looks intimidating but, happily the determinant of the Jacobian of this transformation is

$$-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2 u-v^2}}$$

Thus, you end up with the integral

$$-\int _{-1}^1\int _1^4 8uv\,dudv$$

which is zero. In hindsight, that's totally obvious, as your original integrand has an odd symmetry about the line $y=x$!

Comment: for v=x−y, I can't do v^2=x^2+y^2, because v^2=(x+y)^2

Comment: Is that a question?  Or a statement?

Comment: For the translation  of  (x^2−y^2) i can't use v^2 and for the Jacobian  I am getting 1/(2(x+y))

Comment: I'm still scratching my head, trying to figure out how you got that Jacobian.

Comment: wow thank you so much, but for the x=1/2(v+sqrt(2u-v^2) did you plug u into v?

Comment: Honestly, I solved the system on WolframAlpha.  I think the "alternative approach" that I outlined might be simpler in this regard, since you can just add the equations to cancel the $y$s and subtract them to cancel the $x$s.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It means a lot to have math pros like you to help a little math dummy like me.

Comment: @Andy No problem!  I deleted my alternative approach, as it occurs to me that we don't know the bounds for $u$ and $v$ in that case.  I also added some detail on how to solve for $x$ and $y$ by hand.

Comment: Thanks, a lot you been a big help.

Comment: I don't know if this is right but I think I found a faster way. u=x^2+y^2, v=x-y,  ∬R 8(x^2+y^2)(x^2-y^2)dA =  ∬R 8(u)(v)(x+y) and if the Jacobian is 1/(2(x+y)) then you get  ∬R 4(u)((v). I used (x^2-y^2)=(x-y)(x+y)

Answer (score 2):

This integral is easily evaluated in polar coordinates.  Obviously, $r \in [1,2]$.  The bounds on the angle $\theta$ depend on $r$ and are derived from the lines:

$$y-x=\pm 1 \implies r(\sin{\theta} - \cos{\theta}) = \pm 1$$

Using $$\sin{\theta}-\cos{\theta} = 2 \cos{\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)} \sin{\left(\theta-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}$$

we get the bounds on $\theta$ as

$$\theta \in \left [ \frac{\pi}{4}-\arcsin{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} r}\right)},  \frac{\pi}{4}+\arcsin{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} r}\right)}\right ]$$

The integral is now

$$8 \int_1^2 dr \, r^5 \: \int_{\pi/4 - \arcsin{(1/(\sqrt{2} r))}}^{\pi/4 + \arcsin{(1/(\sqrt{2} r))}} d\theta \, \cos{2 \theta}$$

Note that I used $x^2-y^2 = r^2 (\cos^2{\theta} - \sin^2{\theta}) = r^2 \cos{2 \theta}$.

The integral over $\theta$ is  simple and turns out to be zero:

$$\int_{\pi/4 - \arcsin{(1/(\sqrt{2} r))}}^{\pi/4 + \arcsin{(1/(\sqrt{2} r))}} d\theta \, \cos{2 \theta} = \frac12 \sin{\left ( \frac{\pi}{2} + 2 \arcsin{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} r}\right)}\right )} - \frac12 \sin{\left ( \frac{\pi}{2} -2 \arcsin{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} r}\right)}\right )}$$

which you should see is zero by expanding the sines (noting that $\cos{(\pi/2)} = 0$).  Therefore the integral is zero.

Comment: Do you think my way would work? $u=x^2+y^2, v=x-y, ∬R 8(x^2+y^2)(x^2-y^2)dA = ∬R 8(u)(v)(x+y)$ and if the Jacobian is$ 1/(2(x+y))$ then you get$ ∬R 4(u)((v)$. I used$ (x^2-y^2)=(x-y)(x+y)$

Comment: @Andy: My point in posting my answer is that the problem doesn't require fancy or imaginative coordinate transformations. Very basic polar coordinates not only work, but are natural for this problem.  As far as your way, I am sure that if carried out correctly (including computing the Jacobian), it would work fine.  But I think my solution is simpler and more elegant.

Comment: Thank You Ron you have been a big help today!